# Why and how does Tor browser block SVG assets when set to safest?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Refactoring a website to be compatible with "safest" setting, but wasn't able to find documentation of this feature.

**Edit:** Found how... `about:config` => `svg.disabled` => `true`.

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question. Instead add it as anwer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @JensKubieziel... that being said, I don't understand... First you recommended not adding an answer and then to "add it as answer". Puzzled.

Comment: @sunknudsen, he meant posting the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### How the Tor browser disables SVG images:

The Tor browser design and implementation document states for the high security preference:

> This security level inherits the preferences from the Medium level, and additionally disables remote fonts (noscript.forbidFonts), completely disables JavaScript (by unsetting noscript.globalHttpsWhitelist), **and disables SVG images (svg.in-content.enabled).**

**However, I have reason to believe this is false and this document is not up to date.**

The Tor Browser now disables SVG images by setting  `svg.disabled` to true. I verified this to be the case when I checked the status of `svg.disabled`. It showed up as true for `safest` security level and false for any other security level.

---

#### Why the Tor browser does this:

SVGs create vulnerabilities including XSS attacks (Cross-Site-Scripting), HTML injection, The Billion Laughs Attack, DOS attacks, etc.

See more here:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11384/exploits-or-other-security-risks-with-svg-upload
- https://medium.com/axdb/stored-cross-site-scripting-attacks-using-crafted-svg-images-1b09c9e727e4

Answer (score 0):

Figured out why... see https://www.fortinet.com/blog/threat-research/scalable-vector-graphics-attack-surface-anatomy.

In a nutshell, SVGs add a lot of attack surface including scripting and injection attacks.